# Custom error handling in makefile

Tags: error-handling, makefile

I need to build a C program which requires a particular Linux package.  I set a variable, PACKAGENOTIFICATION, to a shell command which is supposed to check if the package is installed for Ubuntu and print a notification if not:

```
PACKAGENOTIFICATION := if cat /etc/issue | grep Ubuntu -c >>/dev/null; then if ! dpkg -l | grep libx11-dev -c >>/dev/null; then echo "<insert notification here>"; fi; fi

[...]

maintarget: dependencies
            $(PACKAGENOTIFICATION)
            other_commands
```

Unfortunately, while making the dependencies, it runs into the files which need the package, and errors out before executing my PACKAGENOTIFICATION.  An alternative formulation is to make a separate target whose only purpose is to run the notification:

```
maintarget: notify other_dependencies
            commands

notify: 
            $(PACKAGENOTIFICATION)
```

However, since this phantom dependency always needs to be executed, make never reports that the program is up to date.

What's the best way to have make always report as up to date, but also execute my notification before it dies?

Thanks!

Comment: @Beta Whatever comes with the most recent version of Ubuntu, I'm afraid I don't know how to check.  Ideally, though, any solution should work with all versions that are still widely used, in addition to being disto-independent (although the above code is already sadly lacking on that front).

Comment: You can try `make -v` to determine the version. It's probably a reasonably modern version of GNUMake, which means it'll allow order-only prerequisites. Writing makefiles that work with non-GNU versions of Make is a real pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your version of Make supports "order-only" prerequisites, this will do it:

```
# Note the pipe
maintarget: other_dependencies | notify
            commands

# This should be an order-only preq of any target that needs the package
notify: 
            $(PACKAGENOTIFICATION)
```

If not, there are other approaches.

Comment: It's GNU Make 3.81.  And it works!  I just had to invert the order:
`maintarget: | notify other_dependencies
            commands`